# Divergence using Free Monads

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use a data types a la carte approach to define a free monad for templating purposes.  I have written a few combinators, but I am stuck.  My program keeps diverging, and I don't see why.

Consider:

```
math :: Math :<: f => MathExpr a -> Free f ()
blank :: f :<: (Textual :+: Math) => Free f () -> Free (Blank k f) ()
equals :: Free (Math :+: (Blank L Math)) ()
       -> Free (Math :+: (Blank R Math)) ()
       -> Free Equation ()
```

The composition (blank . math) has the type:

```
blank . math :: ( f :<: (Textual :+: Math)
                , Math :<: f
                ) => MathExpr a -> Free (Blank k f) ()
```

Notice that f must be simultaneously less than the join of Textual and Math, and greater than Math.  So the only possibility for f is Math.  (I realize the compiler can't infer this without more work on my part, if at all)

The problem happens when I try to evaluate:

```
test :: Free Equation ()
test = (hoistFree (inj :: Blank 'L Math a -> (Math :+: Blank 'L Math) a)
     . blank
     . (math :: MathExpr x -> Free Math ())
     $ "hi"
     )
     `equals` (math $ "world")
```

which apparently loops, pegging my CPU at 100%.  The computation prints its result as:

```
Free (Equation (Free (DirectSum {unDirectSum = Right
```

at which point the value is truncated and GHCi quits.  So it apparently gets as far as figuring out that the first argument to equals is in the latter part of the direct sum, but it doesn't seem t be able to compute blank.

All my functions are total and I don't see a bottom here, but I was never any good at fixed point combinators.  Any ideas?

Edit:  The module with the free monad is now at:  http://lpaste.net/93471
       The module Data.Domain is at: http://lpaste.net/93472

Comment: Can you put the code in lpaste?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: Edited to include code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'm making this lame answer…)

The code from your lpastes works for me (almost) with GHC 7.6.3 and free-3.4.2

I did have to change some things in order to make it typecheck, but they were pretty simple.

- Replace (MathExpr a) with Text.
- Add -XKindSignatures and -XOverloadedStrings.
- Use standalone deriving for the (Show Blank) derivation.

  deriving instance (Show (g (Free g ())), Show f) => Show (Blank k g f)

I can only imagine the last of those effecting termination.

After those changes, I see this in ghci:

```
*> test
Free (Equation (Free (DirectSum {unDirectSum = Right (Blank (Free (Math "hi" (Pure ()))) (Pure ()))})) (Free (DirectSum {unDirectSum = Left (Math "hello" (Pure ()))})) (Pure ()))
```

So, perhaps you're using an out-of-date/buggy combination of GHC and free? HTH.

Comment: Interesting.  I had "instance (Show (g (Free g ()), Show f) => Show (Blank k g f)" in my code, without "deriving" or a "show" definition.  I wonder if Generic deriving was making a looping instance.  It would normally show a method missing error without a show method.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that trouble with the via-Generic derivation sounds worrisome. Thanks for mentioning that, I'll look into it.

Comment: I think our diagnosis was wrong.  I made a "ToBuilder" class which maps Free (Things) () to lazy text builders and I ended up with a pretty massive space leak.  Rendering the template that encodes "hi = hello" uses up about 2000MB of ram and 30% of my cpu.  If a lazy space leak is the problem for a text builder, I'm sure it was the problem for string.  I'm going to try strict text now.

Comment: Actually, I found a bug in my implementation of toBuilder.  :)